# Share requests.Session between processes in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I want to share slightly modified version of requests.Session between multiple python processes via multiprocessing but a weird thing is happening to me. Both through Queue and Manager the requests.Session object I get is stripped down of my modifications.

```
 s = requests.Session()
 s._my_custom_field = "test"

 q = multiprocessing.Queue()
 q.put(s)
 s_from_queue = q.get(s)
 s_from_queue._my_custom_field

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute '_my_custom_field'
```

Same thing happens with Manager. Any thoughts why is this happening and how I should share requests.Session between processes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since IO is not CPU intensive, you could consider using multiprocessing.dummy which uses threads instead of processes. That way you could use the the same Session in memory across threads.